# Find conversation thread between 2 users excluding group conversations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a basic private messaging system which is capable of having 1 to 1 conversations and group conversations.

Currently I have a "Send Message" widget box across the site where the user can type in the name of the user and send a message to them which begins a "1 to 1" conversation thread.

What I need this widget to do is, when a message is sent, check to see if a conversation between the two users already exists, and if it does, add the new message to the already existing conversation thread. If the conversation does not exist, then start a new thread.

My main issue is, how can I exclude checking **group** conversation threads where both users are participants.

A snippet of the 2 relevant tables are as follows:

**threads Table:**

- Title
- Type

**thread_participants Table**

- thread_id
- user_id

The thread "type" determines if the thread is a "single" (1-1 conversation) or "group" conversation.

My theory is to search through the thread table finding where two users are in the same thread however I am unsure how I can do this using eloquent in my controller.

Hope that is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the Laracast forum, i was able to come up with this:

```
$threadBetweenTwoUsers = Thread::whereIn('id', $userParticipant)->where('type', 'single')
->whereHas( 'participants', function($query) use ($recipient_id){ 
    $query->where('user_id', $recipient_id); // filter by other participant
})
->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select your relevant information from the threads table and join it to the thread_participants and aliase the table thread_participants (e.g. as new_thread_participants) and join to it again. In your conditions you can then specify you limiters

```
DB::table('threads')
->select('some_columns')
->join('thread_participants', 'threads.id', '=', 'thread_participants.thread_id')
->join('thread_participants AS new_table', 'threads.id', '=', 'new_table.thread_id')
->where('threads.type', 'single')
->where('thread_participants.user_id', user_1_id)
->where('new_table.user_id', user_2_id)
->get();
```

This may also help https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp